# what are the object types in postgresql 9.4.5

Tags: postgresql, object

iam working on Postgresql 9.4.5. Would like to know the various object types available in Postgresql for which "Change ownership" command is applicable.

e.g. 
user1 creates below table:

```
# create table testschema1.testtable1(id int);
```

super user changing this table ownership to user2:

```
# alter table testschema1.testtable1 owner to user2;
```

Could any one advise that what are the various object types ?

ManyThanks,

Comment: Did my answer in any way help you?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list that I know of:

- Aggregate
- Collation
- Conversion
- Database
- Domain
- Event trigger
- Foreign data wrapper
- Foreign table
- Function
- Language
- Large Object
- Materialized view
- Operator
- Operator class
- Operator family
- Schema
- Sequence
- Server
- Table
- Tablespace
- Text search configuration
- Text search dictionary
- Type
- View
- List item

Feel free to edit the answer to include additional objects that can have their ownership transfered.

Also, be sure to check Postgres documentation regarding [**SQL Commands**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html)